# Cannot find a differ supporting object NgStyle backgroundImage

Tags: angular

I am trying to display an image inside a div with Angular

I have:

```
<div 
  ngStyle="{'backgroundImage': 'url({{getImage()}})'}"
>
  <div class="text-wrapper">
    text
  </div>
</div>
```

And the address of the pic I am getting through:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.fullImagePath = 'assets/hackaton_home.png';
  }

  getImage() {
    return this.fullImagePath;
  }
```

The image is located in the folder assets.

The error that I get is:

[image]

Any help?

Answer (score 4):

```
<div [ngStyle]="{ 'background-image': 'url(' + fullImagePath+ ')'}"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 [ngStyle]="{'backgroundImage': 'url({{getImage()}})'}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not add just the path variable

```
<div 
  [ngStyle]="{'background-image': 'url(' + fullImagePath + ')'}"
>
```

If you absolutely want to call a function then use the similar syntax

```
<div 
  [ngStyle]="{'background-image': 'url(' + getImage() + ')'}"
>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the returned url to the variable, change it as follows,

```
 [ngStyle]="{'background-image':'url('+ getImage()')'}"
```